# What is the meaning of ゴト in the context of 鮎

Tags: word-requests, word-usage, food

I ate in a place with 鮎ラーメン. The store employee can't explain it but I think it's something to do with the cut of the 鮎. It was butterfly cutted.

For cutting what would be the kanji for go-to. 毎? 丸毎 shortcut for the marugoto?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

丸ごと means "whole" and ごと is usually written in *kana*. By "butterfly" I guess you mean what would be called 鮎のひらき, which means the fish would be "cleaned" (gutted) but skin, bones, head, fins, etc. would not be removed.

I guess the store employee was trying to explain to you that you would be served the whole fish, rather than a filet.

Answer (score 0):

You see the word ゴトin the red circle(マル),
and it means マルゴトas you understand it, as a whole.

Comment: yeah, japanese have been difficult becaue of all the slang abbreviation. I guess it is the same in all languages.